# MySQL and User Authentication - Strong evidence for inside query versus after query?

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication

This is a real no brainer, but I feel like I've never heard an "official" verdict on this, maybe because it doesn't matter or maybe because it's so obvious and I've just missed it.

So there are three options as I see it:

1. Check user/password in MySQL query (assuming everything has been sanitized and/or prepared and the passwords are stored salted and hashed):

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users WHERE user = '$user' && pass = '$pass';
   ```
2. Query for user/password and check in code:

   ```
   SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user = '$user';
   ```
3. Something else I'm totally unaware of and should be doing.

Is there a clear reason to go with 1 or 2, and if there is a 3, I'm all ears.

Comment: This (my own question) may be relevant: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46451/are-two-database-trips-reasonable-for-a-login-system

Comment: @RandolphWest - In your scenario, you are using a new salt each login, right? So I think our questions are fundamentally the same, eg "How much of this is safe to do in the database query?" But now that I see your method I'm feeling a tad insufficient.  Can I run down a few more details of my authentication and get some feedback from you? At the end of the day, the data on my system is being protected from the users (who don't have the background for rainbow tables) and has little to no value outside of the group, but I want to confirm I'm not missing some fundamentals for future applications.

Comment: Sure thing. I have contact details on my profile page.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a version of your #2 is best - most often you're going to want to know something else about the user (such as a unique ID, or their full name, or whatever might be relevant in your application) so you'd have to do another query once they had authenticated successfully.

I'm agnostic about whether you check authentication in MySQL or application code - it depends on where you do the hashing/decryption/whatever, and just needs to be secure and work.

If you read in the information as part of the authentication step in the query, then you've got all you need for later. And if the query fails or doesn't give you the password hash you expect, you can deal with it and no harm done.

Comment: The system I've got in place is a server-side session token that's randomly generated after they have been validated the first time. I take the random token, their IP, and their UA string and create a hash. Their session ID is regenerated on each page load. So if the session hash doesn't match, they get sent back to GO and I collect username and password. The password is compared (either in the DB or the in code) to their SHA1 password and if it matches, we start the dance again.  Do you think it's missing the element of a nonce, ie a random number that gets checked page-to-page? Or something?